# Cannot change the color of status line

Tags: statusline, macos

I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065941/how-can-i-change-vim-status-line-color):

```
hi StatusLine ctermfg=red
highlight statisline ctermfg=red
hi! statusline ctermfg=008
hi statusline ctermfg=008
hi statusline cterm=bold
hi StatusLineNC ctermfg=2 ctermbg=8 cterm=NONE
hi StatusLineNC ctermfg=2 ctermbg=8 cterm=NONE
```

Nothing changes.

macOS, the latest Vim 8 from Brew, in default terminal.

My [vimrc](https://bitbucket.org/vitaly-zdanevich/vim-config/raw/a92504e544c60e03344ce8b4d577dcf2886156ff/vimrc).

Comment: The spelling should be StatusLine and StatusLineNC. Your question has wrong spelling. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I tried `StatusLine` too.

Comment: If you don't mind me saying so, your vimrc needs serious tending. Please have the decency to at least use `augroup` enclosing the `autocmd`s.

Comment: @EnanAjmain yes I was a little ashamed to post my vimrc here, I need to prettify it...

Comment: @EnanAjmain besides `augroup` - what is your other recommendations for my `vimrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions, try them all:

- Check if you're using `set termguicolors` in your vimrc. If yes, then either disable it or use `guibg` and `guifg` instead of `ctermbg` and `ctermfg` respectively.
- Check if you're calling for changing the colorscheme after you set your statusline highlights. You should call your colorscheme *before* you set personalized statusline highlights.

That should do it.

**Edit**:

You currently have groupwise highlight set to User{N}, i.e. your vimrc has:

```
set statusline=%1*%F%h%m%=\ [%p%%]\ [%l/%L]:%c
```

see the part with %1*? that's what I'm talking about. The solutions are

- Remove it.
  Or,
- Read through the help docs `:h statusline` and learn to use User{N} highlight properly, specially the part about

  ```
  * -   Set highlight group to User{N}, where {N} is taken from the
    minwid field, e.g. %1*.  Restore normal highlight with %* or %0*.
    The difference between User{N} and StatusLine  will be applied
    to StatusLineNC for the statusline of non-current windows.
    The number N must be between 1 and 9.  See |hl-User1..9|
  ```

Comment: I tried the last line in my `vimrc` and entering commands in running Vim, nothing; my `vimrc` without `set termguicolors` :(

Comment: That's odd. Could you link your vimrc in the post?

Comment: Added link to vimrc.

Comment: Got what's wrong. Edited the post. At first paste this at the very bottom of your vimrc, `set statusline=%t%m%=%l,%v` and check if the error is fixed. After that read the answer above.